# Compile with pyinstaller one executable including data files

Tags: python, compilation, pyinstaller

According with [pyinstaller documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-data-files). to include data files one should include relative path to that files in datas. In my case it works but the executable looks up my data files in original folders. I have checked temp folders and it uncompress them. If I remove those files from foldere where code is the it does not works.The goal is to compile it in one executable.Here is my *spec code:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None
data_files = [('sht.css', "."), ("widgets/shth.css", "widgets")]

a = Analysis(['applicationName.py'],
             pathex=['/home/iuser/dev/python/applicationName'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=data_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='applicationName',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
```

Comment: you want to cram css files into your exe?

Comment: Yes, actually it is linux executable.

Comment: I don't think it works like that. Maybe there is magic I don't know about, but i'd be surprised if you could do it with pyinstaller.